# c++-mode-map does not stay empty after (setq c++-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))

Tags: keymap, c++

I don't like all the major mode bindings. So I usually just `(setq the-map-in-question (make-sparse-keymap))` each time I come across a new major mode.

But for c++-mode-map, it does not remain empty.
I use `help-fns+.el` to display the bindings of the keymap. When I open emacs, `c++-mode-map` is indeed empty. But as soon as I open a C++ file, the following bindings in the keymap (in the picture) appears.

Why?
[image: Picture of the keymaps that appears in c++-mode-map]

Edit: This part seems to be the problem (in `cc-mode.el`):
[image]

I still don't know how to fix this issue though.

Comment: Doesn't [phils answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/70976/2370) work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messing with keymaps is usually best done after the defining library has loaded.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  (setq c++-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!